# SQL foreign key on number()

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

got a newbie question on adding a foreign key.

Working with a existing ORACLE SQL database, I need to add a new table.

This is my script :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_ASH_CONTACTS (
ASH_ID  number(19,0) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ASH_ADMIN_STAKEHOLDER(ASH_ID), 
ASH_CONTACT_ID number(19,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
ASH_CONTACT_NAME varchar2(80 BYTE),
ASH_CONTACT_TELEFOONNUMMER varchar2(25 BYTE),
ASH_CONTACT_GSMNUMMER varchar2(25 CHAR),
ASH_CONTACT_FAXNUMMER varchar2(25 BYTE),
ASH_CONTACT_EMAILADRES varchar2(100 BYTE),
ASH_CONTACT_WEBSITE varchar2(100 BYTE)     );
```

The existing table ASH_ADMIN_STAKEHOLDER contains a primary key ASH_ID number(19) witch is already used in other existing tables.
When I enter the statement in SQLDEVELOPER worksheet I get a syntax error in the worksheet on the keyword FOREIGN : "syntax error partially recognized rules ..."

I believe I followed the example from w3schools website :

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
OrderID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)   );
```

with the difference that ASH_ID is not a int but number(19,0)

In the image I can show current relationship between the stakeholder table and another table on the same ASH_ID field. [image]

Hope somebody can point me how to do it right ;-)
Any other suggestions on the script like are welcome.

Comment: The data type of the referring columns needs to exactly match the key in the other table, so use `number(19, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

Master table first (has to have a primary or unique key which will then be referenced by a foreign key):

```
SQL> create table ash_admin_stakeholder(ash_id number(19) primary key);

Table created.
```

Detail table: it *works* with correct syntax:

```
SQL> create table test_ash_contacts
  2  (ash_id number(19, 0) constraint fk_con_ash references ash_admin_stakeholder (ash_id));

Table created.
```

---

Or, if you want to use *outline* foreign key constraint:

```
SQL> create table test_ash_contacts
  2  (ash_id number (19, 0),
  3      constraint fk_con_ash foreign key (ash_id)
  4      references ash_admin_stakeholder (ash_id)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Regarding your concern about `INT` vs. `NUMBER(19, 0)`: no problem either:

```
SQL> create table test_ash_contacts
  2  (ash_id int constraint fk_con_ash references ash_admin_stakeholder (ash_id));

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Can't get it working yet. The ide gives me error on that syntax. Are you using Oracle SQL? For now I get it done like this : CREATE TABLE TEST_ASH_CONTACTS(
    ASH_ID NUMBER(19,0) REFERENCES d00ash01.ash_admin_stakeholder(ash_id),     ...The ide from SQLDeveloper does not give an error anymore, but can not test it yet. If any suggestions, still welcome.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, this is Oracle and yes, it *works* (as demonstrated). If it does NOT work for you, then you did something wrong. Can't tell what, but I might if you edit the original message you posted (i.e. not as a comment), exactly as I did: complete commands and the way Oracle responded.

Answer (score 1):

Given a parent table like this:

```
create table ash_admin_stakeholder
( ash_id number(19) primary key );
```

you can either name the constraint explicitly like this:

```
create table test_ash_contacts
( ash_id constraint your_constraint_name references ash_admin_stakeholder(ash_id)
```

or else let Oracle generate the name:

```
create table test_ash_contacts
( ash_id references ash_admin_stakeholder(ash_id)
```

There is no benefit in repeating the datatype for the child table.

By the way, I would also make the identity column a PK, e.g.

```
ash_contact_id number(19,0) generated as identity
               constraint test_ash_contacts_pk primary key
```